# Java RMI - Writing my own custom Observable class

Tags: java, rmi, observable

I'm quite new at Java and Observable-Observer pattern, and I have to transform an already working application, in a distributed one using RMI.
What I've read so far, is that I have to write my own Observer and Observable classes, as the ones already included in Java won't work in RMI.
It wasn't a big challenge, except one of the methods is not being expemplified at any website. I'm talking about the setChanged method.
Usually, when the Observable object changes any attribute value, I do this:

```
this.setChanged();
this.notifyObservers();
```

However, when I'm writing my own version of the Observable class, then I don't know how to write the setChanged method.
What I'd like to know are basically two things:

1) Is there any generic way to implement that method? 
2) What would I lose if I don't implement this method? Would Observable still work?

Comment: I advise you strongly against it. RMI is not a suitable technology for observers or listeners. You need to think at a more coarse-grained level.

Comment: Thank you so much @EJP for the advice. However this is a scholar work I have to do, and one of the requirements is to use that technology. :/ But I see the problems I'm facing on this project and agree with you. Also being forced to use MySQL instead of SQL Server to persist data... I'm not happy at all with this project.